# Measuring the time a thread locks the monitor

Tags: java, performance, locking, profiling

I have lock contention on a semaphore and I would like to measure how much time the lock is kept.

Are there some free tools for measuring such thing ?

Tried Visual VM and I see the lock contention but I am more interested in the times.

Thanks for any sugestion.

I have like 50 of this

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '226' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=3 tid=0x00000001099fa000 nid=0x41e waiting for monitor entry [0xfffffffe5a8f9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:292)
    - waiting to lock <0xfffffffeb063ebb0> (a weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:176)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:723)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:696)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:445)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:342)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Sun Studio Performance Analyzer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/analyzer-qs-136436.html) and enable **lock profiling**. This will show you the time spent in the lock.

jProfiler also has Thread/Monitor statistics tab so you could give it a try.

Another way is to obtain an estimate by **sampling the thread dumps** in given intervals and computing manually.

Yet another way is to **print the Safe Point Statistics** (`+XX:PrintSafePointStatistics`), this prints out also "*amount of time in milliseconds threads spent blocked*", for details see [JVM SafePointStatistics - Can anyone help interpret it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16178074/772000).

Comment: This is what is intended to do :) "Another way is to obtain an estimate by sampling the thread dumps in given intervals and computing manually."

Answer (score 3):

I think you could extend Semaphor, override acquire and log necessary info before and after calling super.acquire().

Comment: Unfortunately the code is built in Adobe Livecycle ... It is actually Xstream used by Livecycle in not optimum way, cause the parser is instantiated on each request

Comment: If you are in Spring you could try and make a Logging Aspect with Spring-AOP.

Comment: thought on that ... don't know how to bundle it with adobe livecycle. i have like 50 of these [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" waiting for lock weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@796f84d8 BLOCKED